# Polish characters in C using files and lists

Tags: c, unicode, io, text-files, special-characters

I need to get proper Polish characters "ąężźćśół". I used some solutions like `setlocale`, `system chcp`, `wchar_t`. Everything goes well as long as I don't use files/lists. `wscanf`, `wprintf` and `wchar_t` works perfectly.

But if I'm trying to read something from a file and save that into a list (even in array), then trying to put that to the screen, I can't get proper Polish characters, and in case of the lists, I'm getting different results from time to time for example, **z`** , **A2** , like random characters from nowhere. I've been trying to get good results by using `fscanf` and `fgets` with w(wide) variations, but it doesn't work. Did I something wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

struct dyk{
    wchar_t line[200];                             
    struct dyk *next;                             
};

typedef struct dyk dyk;


void printdyk(char name[100]){
    dyk *wyp;
    wyp = malloc(sizeof(dyk));
    wchar_t yt[100];
    FILE *dyktando;
    dyktando = fopen(name, "r+");
    if(dyktando == NULL){
        wprintf(L"Błąd otwarcia pliku!\n");                 //Can't open file
    }else{
        fgets(&wyp->line, sizeof(dyk), dyktando);           //reading from file and send to the list
        wprintf(L"%s\n", wyp->line);                        //write text from the list on the screen
        wchar_t yt[100];
        wscanf(L"%s", &yt);                                 //testing strings comparing, so I have to put some variables
        int n=strcmp(yt, wyp->line);                        //str compare
        printf("%d", n);                                //result, it gives me -1 every time
    }
    fclose(dyktando);
}
```

I tested function with txt file that contents only one character "ż". Can't read from file properly. At the start of main function I put these 2 lines:

```
system("chcp 852");
setlocale(LC_ALL, ".852");
```

I'm using codeblock, mingw32-gcc compiler, and no flags.

Comment: Your call to `fgets` is wrong - should be `fgets(wyp->line, 200*sizeof(wchar_t), dyktando)` as `sizeof(dyk)` includes the "next" as well

Comment: @ChrisTurner thank you! I solved problem about printing text on screen, but have quetion, why there is 200 not 100, and why there's no & near wyp->line?

And there's problem with strcmp, 2 strings show same character fe. ż, but result is still -1

Comment: It is 200 as that is the size of your array in `dyk`. `strcmp` is designed to work with `char` so I'm not sure if it'll work with multibyte characters. You don't need the & as the array will turn into a pointer

Comment: oh right, thanks. Don't you know if there's smth I can switch with this `strcmp`?

Answer (score 2):

You are not using `wchar_t` compatible functions everywhere in your code. In particular:

```
fgets(&wyp->line, sizeof(dyk), dyktando);           //reading from file and send to the list
```

The `wchar_t` compatible version is [`fgetws`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/fgetws/). Also, `wyp->line` (without the `&` operator) is the correct argument.

```
int n=strcmp(yt, wyp->line);                        //str compare
```

[`wcscmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wcscmp/) should be used instead.

Also note that `sizeof` on a `wchar_t` array is not correct when a function expects length in *characters* rather than *bytes* (like `fgetws` does).

Comment: ohhh, now I understand something. I used `fgets`, because `fgetws` gave me bad result. But all of that is because `fgetws` want length in characters, so `sizeof` won't work properly! Could you navigate me how should proper `fgetws` looks like?

Comment: @Amatheon Hint: Given the length of a `wchar_t` buffer in bytes, how would you translate that to the length in `wchar_t`s?

Comment: The size of an array in elements can be determined by using `sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(data_type)`

Answer (score 1):

A comment OP (Amatheon) made indicates that the true underlying problem is how to properly read files using wide-character functions.

To ensure maximum compatibility and portability, let's restrict to C99. Consider the following example program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <wctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

#ifdef   USE_ERRNO_CONSTANTS
#define  SET_ERRNO(value)  (errno = (value))
#else
#define  SET_ERRNO(value)
#endif

ssize_t get_wide_delimited(wchar_t **lineptr, size_t *sizeptr, wint_t delim, FILE *stream)
{
    wchar_t  *line = NULL;
    size_t    size = 0;
    size_t    used = 0;
    wint_t    wc;

    if (!lineptr || !sizeptr || !stream) {
        /* Invalid function parameters. NULL pointers are not allowed. */
        SET_ERRNO(EINVAL);
        return -1;
    }
    if (ferror(stream)) {
        /* Stream is already in error state. */        
        SET_ERRNO(EIO);
        return -1;
    }

    if (*sizeptr > 0) {
        line = *lineptr;
        size = *sizeptr;
    } else {
        *lineptr = NULL;
    }

    while (1) {

        wc = fgetwc(stream);
        if (wc == WEOF || wc == delim)
            break;

        if (used + 1 > size) {
            /* Growth policy.  We wish to allocate a chunk of memory at once,
               so we don't need to do realloc() too often as it is a bit slow,
               relatively speaking.  On the other hand, we don't want to do
               too large allocations, because that would waste memory.
               Anything that makes 'size' larger than 'used' will work.
            */
            if (used < 254)
                size = 256;
            else
            if (used < 65536)
                size = 2 * used;
            else
                size = (used | 65535) + 65521;

            line = realloc(line, size * sizeof (wchar_t));
            if (!line) {
                /* Out of memory. */
                SET_ERRNO(ENOMEM);
                return -1;
            }

            *lineptr = line;
            *sizeptr = size;
        }

        line[used++] = wc;
    }

    if (wc == WEOF) {
        /* Verify that the WEOF did not indicate a read error. */
        if (ferror(stream)) {
            /* Read error. */
            SET_ERRNO(EIO);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    /* Ensure there is enough room for the delimiter and end-of-string mark. */
    if (used + 2 > size) {
        /* We could reuse the reallocation policy here,
           with the exception that the minimum is used + 2, not used + 1.
           For simplicity, we use the minimum reallocation instead.
        */
        size = used + 2;
        line = realloc(line, size * sizeof (wchar_t));
        if (!line) {
            /* Out of memory. */
            SET_ERRNO(ENOMEM);
            return -1;
        }
        *lineptr = line;
        *sizeptr = size;
    }

    /* Append the delimiter, unless end-of-stream mark. */
    if (wc != WEOF)
        line[used++] = wc;

    /* Append the end-of-string nul wide char,
       but do not include it in the returned length. */
    line[used] = L'\0';

    /* Success! */
    return (ssize_t)used;
}

ssize_t get_wide_line(wchar_t **lineptr, size_t *sizeptr, FILE *stream)
{
    return get_wide_delimited(lineptr, sizeptr, L'\n', stream);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t       *line = NULL, *p;
    size_t         size = 0;
    unsigned long  linenum;
    FILE          *in;
    int            arg;

    if (!setlocale(LC_ALL, ""))
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Your C library does not support your current locale.\n");
    if (fwide(stdout, 1) < 1)
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Your C library does not support wide standard output.\n");

    if (argc < 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s FILENAME [ FILENAME ... ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This program will output the named files, using wide I/O.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {

        in = fopen(argv[arg], "r");
        if (!in) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[arg], strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if (fwide(in, 1) < 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Wide input is not supported from this file.\n", argv[arg]);
            fclose(in);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        linenum = 0;

        while (get_wide_line(&line, &size, in) > 0) {
            linenum++;

            /* We use another pointer to the line for simplicity.
               We must not modify 'line' (except via 'free(line); line=NULL; size=0;'
               or a similar reallocation), because it points to dynamically allocated buffer. */
            p = line;

            /* Remove leading whitespace. */
            while (iswspace(*p))
                p++;

            /* Trim off the line at the first occurrence of newline or carriage return.
               (The line will also end at the first embedded nul wide character, L'\0',
                if the file contains any.) */
            p[wcscspn(p, L"\r\n")] = L'\0';

            wprintf(L"%s: Line %lu: '%ls', %zu characters.\n", argv[arg], linenum, p, wcslen(p));
        }

        if (ferror(in)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Read error.\n", argv[arg]);
            fclose(in);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if (fclose(in)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Delayed read error.\n", argv[arg]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        wprintf(L"%s: Total %lu lines read.\n", argv[arg], linenum);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    free(line);
    line = NULL;
    size = 0;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Because the `EINVAL`, `EIO`, and `ENOMEM` errno constants are not defined in the C standards, the `get_wide_line()` and `get_wide_delimited()` only set `errno` if you define the `USE_ERRNO_CONSTANTS` preprocessor value.

The `get_wide_line()` and `get_wide_delimited()` are reimplementations of the `getwline()` and `getwdelim()` functions from ISO/IEC TR 24731-2:2010; the wide-character equivalents of the POSIX.1 [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) and [`getdelim()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html) functions. Unlike `fgets()` or `fgetws()`, these use a dynamically allocated buffer to hold the line, so there is no fixed line length limits, other than available memory.

I've explicitly marked the code to be under [Creative Commons Zero](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/public-domain/cc0/) license: *No Rights Reserved*. It means you can use it in your own code, under whatever license you want.

Note: I would really love users to push their vendors and C standard committee members to get these included in the bog-standard C library part in the next version of the C standard.  As you can see from above, they can be implemented in standard C already; it is just that the C library itself can do the same much more efficiently.  The GNU C library is a perfect example of that (although even they are stalling with the implementation, because lack of standardization).  Just think how many buffer overflow bugs would be avoided if people used `getline()`/`getdelim()`/`getwline()`/`getwdelim()` instead of `fgets()`/`fgetws()`! And avoid having to think about what the maximum reasonable line length in each instance would be to, too.  Win-win!

(In fact, we could switch the return type to `size_t`, and use `0` instead of `-1` as the error indicator.  That would limit the changes to the text of the C standard to the addition of the four functions.  It saddens and irritates me to no end, to have such a significant group of trivial functions so callously and ignorantly overlooked, for no sensible reason.  Please, bug your vendors and any C standards committee members you have access to about this, as incessantly and relentlessly as you can manage. Both you and they deserve it.)

The essential parts of the program are

- `if (!setlocale(LC_ALL, ""))`

  This tells the C library to use the locale the user has specified.

  Please, do not hardcode the locale value into your programs.  In most operating systems, all you need to do is to change the `LANG` or `LC_ALL` environment variable to the locale you want to use, before running your program.

  You might think that *"well, I can hardcode it this time, because this is the locale used for this data"*, but even that can be a mistake, because new locales can be created at any time.  This is particularly annoying when the character set part is hardcoded. For example, the ISO 8859 single-byte character set used in Western Europe is ISO 8859-15, not ISO 8859-1, because ISO 8859-15 has the € character in it, whereas ISO 8859-1 does not.  If you have hardcoded ISO 8859-1 in your program, then it cannot correctly handle the € character at all.
- `if (fwide(stream, 1) < 1)` for both `stdout` and file handles

  While the C library does internally do an equivalent of the [`fwide()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwide.3.html) call based on which type of I/O function you use on the file handle the very first time, the explicit check is much better.

  In particular, if the C library cannot support wide I/O to the file or stream represented by the handle, `fwide()` will return negative. (Unless the second parameter is also zero, it should never return zero; because of the issues in standardization, I recommend a strict return value check approach in this case, to catch vendors who decide to try to make life as difficult as possible for programmers trying to write portable code while technically still fulfilling the standard text, like Microsoft is doing.  They even stuffed the C standard committee with their own representatives, so they could tweak C11 away from C99 features they didn't want to support, plus get a stamp of approval of their own nonstandard extensions nobody used before, to help create barriers for developers writing portable C code. Yeah, I don't trust their behaviour at all.)
- `ssize_t len = get_wide_line(&line, &size, handle);`

  If you initialize `wchar_t *line = NULL;` and `size_t  size = 0;` prior to first call to `get_wide_line()` or `get_wide_delimited()`, the function will dynamically resize the buffer as needed.

  The return value is negative if and only if an error occurs. (The functions should never return zero.)

  When a line is read successfully, the return value reflects the number of wide characters in the buffer, including the delimiter (newline, `L'\n'` for `get_wide_delimited()`), and is always positive (greater than zero). The contents in the buffer will have a terminating end-of-wide-string character, `L'\0'`, but it is not counted in the return value.

  Note that when the delimiter is not `L'\0'`, the buffer may contain embedded wide nul characters, `L'\0'`. In that case, `len > wcslen(line)`.

  The above example programs skips any leading whitespace on each input line, and trims off the line at the first linefeed (`L'\n'`), carriage return (`L'\r'`), or nul (`L'\0'`). Because of this, the return value `len` is only checked for success (a positive return value greater than zero).
- `free(line); line = NULL; size = 0;`

  It is okay to discard the line at any point its contents are no longer needed.  I recommend explicitly setting the line pointer to NULL, and the size to zero, to avoid use-after-free bugs.  Furthermore, that allows any following `get_wide_line()` or `get_wide_delimited()` to correctly dynamically allocate a new buffer.
- `ferror(handle)` after a wide input function fails

  Just like with narrow streams and EOF, there are two cases why wide input functions might return `WEOF` (or return -1, depending on the function): because there is no more input, or because a read error occurred.

  There is no reason whatsoever to write computer programs that ignore read or write errors, without reporting them to the user.  Sure, they are rare, but not so rare that a programmer can sanely expect them to never occur.  (In fact, with Flash memory on flimsy circuits stored in weak plastic housings and subjected to human-sized stresses (I've sat on mine time and time again), the errors aren't that rare.)  It is just evil, rather similar to food preparers being too lazy to wash their hands, causing fecal bacteria outbreaks every now and then.  Don't be a fecal bacteria spreader equivalent programmer.

---

Let's say you have a harebrained lecturer who does not allow you to use the above `get_wide_line()` or `get_wide_delimited()` functions.

Don't worry. We can implement the same program using [`fgetws()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetws.3.html), if we restrict line to some fixed upper limit (of wide characters). Lines longer than that will read as two or more lines instead:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <wctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

#ifndef  MAX_WIDE_LINE_LEN
#define  MAX_WIDE_LINE_LEN  1023
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t        line[MAX_WIDE_LINE_LEN + 1], *p;
    unsigned long  linenum;
    FILE          *in;
    int            arg;

    if (!setlocale(LC_ALL, ""))
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Your C library does not support your current locale.\n");
    if (fwide(stdout, 1) < 1)
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Your C library does not support wide standard output.\n");

    if (argc < 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s FILENAME [ FILENAME ... ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This program will output the named files, using wide I/O.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {

        in = fopen(argv[arg], "r");
        if (!in) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[arg], strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if (fwide(in, 1) < 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Wide input is not supported from this file.\n", argv[arg]);
            fclose(in);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        linenum = 0;

        while (1) {

            /* If line is an array, (sizeof line / sizeof line[0]) evaluates to
               the number of elements in it.  This does not work if line is a pointer
               to dynamically allocated memory.  In that case, you need to remember
               number of wide characters you allocated for in a separate variable,
               and use that variable here instead. */
            p = fgetws(line, sizeof line / sizeof line[0], in);
            if (!p)
                break;

            /* Have a new line. */
            linenum++;

            /* Remove leading whitespace. */
            while (iswspace(*p))
                p++;

            /* Trim off the line at the first occurrence of newline or carriage return.
               (The line will also end at the first embedded nul wide character, L'\0',
                if the file contains any.) */
            p[wcscspn(p, L"\r\n")] = L'\0';

            wprintf(L"%s: Line %lu: '%ls', %zu characters.\n", argv[arg], linenum, p, wcslen(p));
        }

        if (ferror(in)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Read error.\n", argv[arg]);
            fclose(in);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if (fclose(in)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Delayed read error.\n", argv[arg]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        wprintf(L"%s: Total %lu lines read.\n", argv[arg], linenum);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Aside from the function used to read each line, the difference is that instead of keeping the while loop condition as `while ((p = fgetws(line, ...))) { ... }`, I changed to the `while (1) { p = fgetws(line, ...); if (!p) break; ...` form that I believe is more readable.

I did deliberately show the longer, more complicated-looking one first, and this simpler one last, in the hopes that you would see that the more complicated-looking one actually has the simpler `main()` -- if we don't just count lines of code or something equally silly, but look at how many opportunities for mistakes there are.

As OP themselves wrote in a comment, the size of the buffer passed to `fgets()` or `fgetws()` is a real issue. There are rules of thumb, but they all suffer from being fragile against edits (especially the differences between arrays and pointers). With `getline()`/`getdelim()`/`getwline()`/`getwdelim()`/`get_wide_line()`/`get_wide_delimited()`, the rule of thumb is `wchar_t *line = NULL; size_t size = 0; ssize_t len;` and `len = get_wide_line(&line, &size, handle);`. No variations, and simple to remember and use.  Plus it gets rid of any fixed limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I an have interesting solution that worked for me after hours of research. I also had a problem wich handling polish characters from a file.

1. Include <locale.h>
2. system("chcp 1250") - at the beggining of program(it changes your console coding)
3. setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ".1250");
4. And convert your txt to Ansi - this 4 steps is all i needed after a lot of research